# Log file not opening on the click of hyperlink in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

We've built a java program where a process begins and start entering logs into a log fie which is always kept at the same location. Every time the process begins, a new log file will be generated with the time stamp in its name (eg: Process_16-11-2013-11-11.log, Process_16-11-2013-13-56.log). As soon as the process ends, we display to user a hyperlink on the jsp. This link contains path of the log file. User can click this link to view the log file.

```
<%
HashMap bundleDetails = new HashMap();
String bundleCommonLocation = prop.getProperty("bundleCommonLocation"); 
    bundleDetails.put("currentLogFileName", bundleCommonLocation + "propagateBundle_"+dateFormat(startDatedt)+".log");
%>

<div id="fileLink">
    <a target="_blank" href="<%=bundleDetails.get("currentLogFileName") %>">Click here to view log file</a>
</div>
```

In the above code,

> prop.getProperty

is fetching value from properties file. When I point to the hyperlink, I can see a well formed hyperlink. If I click on it, nothing happens. Page stays where it is. I tried to open it in new window by right clicking and selecting the appropriate option but that didn't work too.
Weird thing is if I right click and select 'Copy Link Address' and then paste this in a new tab and hit  Enter, the log file opens properly.
Points worth noting:

1. We're running application on tomcat
2. jsp contains java code as it's a maintenance over legacy code, so can't prevent putting in java stuff in jsp
3. Excerpt of hyperlink from the source code  after jsp loads:

   `<div id="fileLink"><a target="_blank" href="D:\IQProcess\Common\Bundles\propagateBundle_2013-11-17-03-49.log">Click here to view log file</a></div>`
4. My css is not causing any problem as I removed id "fileLink" from css and then ran it.Got same problem.
5. The log file is formed dynamically when the process is running. Although the hyperlink in question is displayed at the end of the process, it is formed at the start of the process, that means before the log file actually forms. But we keep it hidden and display to the user only after the process execution completes. Can this be the cause?
   **EDIT**
   Just to clarify, the tomcat server is located on a remote machine and user is running program on his local machine. Before displaying the hyperlink to the user, we successfully copy the log file from tomcat machine to the user specific local machine and this hyperlink try to open file located on this user specific local machine.

Comment: Is the user always on the same machine that your tomcat server is running on?  If not, you're not going to be able to just put a path to the file in your href.  Even if so, you should still prefix the href value with `file:///`.

Comment: @Tap Thank you Tap. The user is on different machine than tomcat but before displaying the hyperlink, I've copied the log file from remote tomcat running machine to the user specific local machine. I tried your suggestion but no luck. Updating the log file location info in my question. Thanks for pointing that out!!